# Replacing text using a filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-filter

Can't get my filter to work. I'm trying to remove the `<br>` tags and replace them with `""`

So far I have this in my view:

```
<span ng-bind-html="description | stripbreaks"></span>
```

and my filter is:

```
.filter('stripbreaks', function(text){
    return text.replace(/<br>/g, '');
});
```

but I'm getting the following error: **Unknown provider: textProvider <- text <- stripbreaksFilter**

This is the first time I've used my own filter so anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had wrong syntax. Basically the outer `function` of filter stands for injecting dependency, and then the inner function gets called on each digest cycle to updated view.

The *Unknown provider: textProvider <- text <- stripbreaksFilter* error occured because you were put `text` inside the outer function

**Filter**

```
.filter('stripbreaks', function(){
   return function(text){
      return text.replace(/<br>/g, '');
   }
});
```

Comment: you still need to return a **function(text){ ... }**, however

Comment: @shershen thanks man for heads up.. I did edit in my answer :-)

Comment: @tommyd456 Pleased to know that.. Cheers & Thanks :-)